# Padding between characters in a string

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have a java application where I draw a String.
[image]

Now I would like to adjust the white space before and after each character that they would fit to the grid (each char in their own square). How can I accomplish that? Thank you for your answers.

```
public class FontTesting extends Applet {

private final int gridSize=20;
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    paintBackground(g2d);
    String text1 = "atzlipjnmr . . A|";
    String text2 = "HHHHHHHHHH . . I|";
    String text3 = "WWWWWWWWWW , , 9|";
    String text4 = "ATATATATAT      |";
    Font font = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20);

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.setFont(font);

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.drawString(text1, 20, 36);

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.drawString(text2.toUpperCase(), 20, 56);

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.drawString(text3.toUpperCase(), 20, 76);

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.drawString(text4.toUpperCase(), 20, 96);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Frame f = new Frame("Antialiased Text Sample");

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    f.add(new FontTesting());
    f.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    f.setSize(new Dimension(300, 180));
    f.setVisible(true);
}
private void paintBackground(Graphics2D g2){
    g2.setPaint(Color.GRAY);
    for (int i = 0; i < getSize().width; i += gridSize) {
      Shape line = new Line2D.Float(i, 0, i, getSize().height);
      g2.draw(line);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < getSize().height; i += gridSize) {
      Shape line = new Line2D.Float(0, i, getSize().width, i);
      g2.draw(line);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could you share us your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw your text Strings character by character into the grid. Have a look at this method.

```
private void paintText(Graphics2D g2, int row, String text){
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
        g2.drawString(Character.toString(text.charAt(i)), i * gridSize, row * gridSize);   
    }  
}
```

You can use it in our `paint()` mathod like this.

```
paintText(g2d, 1, text1);
paintText(g2d, 2, text2);
[...]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. But I encountered another problem. I will be drawing a String which I will get from a .txt file. The problem is how will I know when do I have to go to next row if txt file will have more than one row?

Comment: If you read all text from file into a `String` you could split it by newline character `\n` and write something like this: `int i = 1; for(String line : text.split("\n")) paintText(g2d, i++, line);`